# Driver name for derby 10.7 in-memory

Tags: java, jdbc, derby, in-memory-database

Can any one tell the driver name for derby 10.7 in memory mode?
We are using below for in-memory:

```
org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver
```

and below for filesystem based (for previous derby version):

```
org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
```

I found that for 10.7 , file-system based, driver name should be:

```
org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyTenSevenDialect
```

So is there any change for in-memory driver name?

Comment: The last one is hibernate dialect, it is not a driver.

Answer (score 3):

You can access an in-memory database via the embedded driver or the network driver if the in-memory db is exposed to the network. You have to specify the JDBC connection URL correctly though.

http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.11/devguide/cdevdvlpinmemdb.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your terminology. Derby has two different environments in which it can run: Embedded, and Client/Server. See: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.8/getstart/cgsquck70629.html

The JDBC driver names that you have (EmbeddedDriver and ClientDriver) are correct. http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.8/getstart/rgsquck35368.html

It looks like you are including Hibernate in your application, as DerbyTenSevenDialect is a Hibernate class, not a Derby class. You need to consult the Hibernate community and documentation for Hibernate information.